# Choosing the frame work in core netcoreapp1.0 vs netstandard1.6

Tags: entity-framework-core

I Am creating a DAL layer for my application.
and when I reference this in my web app, it works as expected.
even the Scaffold-DbContext commands work fine and generates the necessary contexts. I used the following is the project.json:

```
 {
"version": "1.0.0-*",
      "buildOptions": {
        "emitEntryPoint": false
      },

      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.0.1",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",

        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.0"
        }  },
      "tools": {
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
      },
      "frameworks": {
        "netcoreapp1.0": {
          "imports": [ "portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81", "portable-net45+win8+wp8", "dnxcore50" ]
        }
      }
    }
```

The moment I try to change the framework to "netstandard1.6", i can't run the Scaffold-DbContext commands from the Package manager console, following is the changed project.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint":false
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.0.1"
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": [ "portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81", "portable-net45+win8+wp8", "dnxcore50" ]
    }
  }
}
```

My question is, does it matter if my DAL dll has the framework as netcoreapp1.0 or netstandard1.6 ? if so then whats the resolution to run the Scaffold-DbContext command on proj with netstandard1.6 as framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, in the end, it *shouldn't* matter. However, the EF tooling is still in pre-release and there are many rough edges. You're seeing issue [#5320](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5320). Passing your main application as the `-StartupProject` should workaround the issue.